# "He rallied his friends to help <him> <himself>." — What's the difference between "him" and "himself"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, reflexive-pronouns

I'd like to understand the difference between "him" and "himself" in the following sentences:

---

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rally):
**(1)** *He rallied his friends **to** help **him***.
I think "*him*" and "*he*" can refer to the same person, and (1) means:
**(1a)** *He gathered his friends who could help him*.
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

my variant:
**(2)** *He rallied his friends **to** help **himself***.
I think (2) is correct and means:
**(2a)** *He gathered his friends in order to help himself*.
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

my variant:
**(3)** *He rallied his friends **in order to** help **him***.
I think if "*him*" and "*he*" refer to the same person, then (3) is incorrect.
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

my variant:
**(4)** *He rallied his friends **in order to** help **himself***.
I think (4)  is correct and means the same as (2).
Am I right?
If not, then why not?

---

P.S.:
As I understood, "*rallied*" here means "*gathered*".
So since "*gathered*" is much more understandable to me, I replaced "*rallied*" with "*gathered*".

Comment: Rallied means more than "gathered".  It means to unite people by awakening in them a fervent desire to achieve a common goal.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that *himself* is reflexive. One might say, "He helped himself," referring back to the subject. E.G., "He helped himself to the food on the cart."

However, in "He rallied his friends to help himself," *he* is not helping himself, it's his *friends* who will be of help to *him*.

In "He gathered his friends *in order* to help himself," the reflexive pronoun makes sense, because it refers not to *the person being helped*, but to *the reasoning for the action that person took*.

Comment: You wrote: "_He **gathered** his friends in order to help himself_" makes sense. In the other answer it's written that "_He **rallied** his friends in order to help himself_" is not good. That is, it makes sense with "_gathered_" but is not good with "_rallied_". Therefore, it's very important here what verb to use. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: No, the difference is "in order to"; "He rallied his friends *in order to help* himself," is acceptable.

Comment: "_He rallied his friends **in order to** help him_." — Could you tell me if it means to you "_He rallied his friends **to** help him_" or not?

Answer (score 1):

> (1) He rallied his friends to help him.
> (2) He rallied his friends to help himself.
> (3) He rallied his friends in order to help him.
> (4) He rallied his friends in order to help himself.

The *in order to* versions mean the same as their corresponding infinitive versions.

In (1), *him* refers to *he*, and your interpretation is right.

In (2), with *himself* as opposed to **themselves**, the sentence is understood to mean the same as example(1).  Reflexive pronouns used in this way should be for cases in which the subjects of the verbs are the same as the objects.
Here the understood "subject" of the infinitive *help* is his friends, and hence the sentence is not as clear.

If we must use the reflexive pronoun *himself*, maybe to emphasise that he did the **rallying** himself, we could say

> He rallied his friends **himself** to help **him**.

> He **himself** rallied his friends to help **him**.

Aside to this, if the intended parties to receive the help are his friends, then

> He rallied his friends to help **themselves**.

Comment: You wrote: "_He **rallied** his friends in order to help himself_" is not good. In the other answer it's written that "_He **gathered** his friends in order to help himself_" makes sense. That is, it is not good with "_rallied_" but makes sense with "_gathered_".  Therefore, it's very important here what verb to use. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: I've edited my answer slightly. 
My view about (2) being not as clear is the use of *himself*; the choice of 
*rallied* or *gathered* is not a factor although the words have different meanings.